# Images are just blank after resizing using MS office picture manager

Tags: microsoft-office

Well this sounds pretty awkward as I wasn't there when this happened. Therefore, I'm providing all the possible information as to what exactly happened.

My cousin's brother re-sized all the images to 25% (or so) using MS office picture manager. There were a few pictures that appeared fine after being re sized, but the majority of the pictures are blank (showing a white blank background). All what I can see is a white background, images are in same sizes, also the dimention. Has anyone gone through such a scenario?? or anyone can say what could cause such an issue??

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem last night. I was editing my honeymoon pictures and pushed save and the pictures saved as blank files. After spending my entire night, I figured out how to get the pictures back.

**Delete all the blank photos and then clear your recycling bin so it's empty.

1) Buy or download (bitorrent) "Stellar Phoenix Photo Recovery" software. I think it goes for $40 but I just downloaded it through a bittorrent site with a free password and I was good to go.

2) Run the program...it will probably take a good hour.

3) Go to the recycling tab within the program and find the file type you needed to recover and then choose which folder you want to place the recovered photos.

This was one heck of an annoyance but I got to work and I am thankful.